# Positioning FAB logout/admin button to right top corner

Tags: css

Preface: I'm quite unfamiliar with CSS

I would like to position this FAB button, currently on the bottom right corner of the screen, to the top right corner. The CSS I have for the below FAB is

`"[tooltip]:before {left: 110% !important; right: auto !important}", ".container-fab {right: 0 !important; left: auto !important;}"`

[Image of FAB button on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkPW9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the position of your button fixed, then just give it `position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;` it will give you the fixed button on top right corner.

to give space from right most, just set `right: 15px; top: 15px` in above css.

you will get that button on top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I assume (what I got after reading your question) your button positioned absolute is inside parent div with position relative. You want to button to be on top right corner. I have also added in the code if your are using "[tooltip]:before" as a button

```css
.parent{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.parent::before {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    /* to center the + symbol */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.parent{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="button">+</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```